# C++ program won't end on return

Tags: c++, return

I have a problem. I am unable to exit program when i detect an error.

```
int main()
{
    int N,N1;

    cout<<("Zadejte pocet prvku mnoziny A:")<<endl;
    cin>>N;
        if (N<=0 || cin.fail()){
            cout<<("Nespravny vstup.")<<endl;
            return 1;
        }
    int *A=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N); /***********/

    cout<<("Zadejte prvky mnoziny A:")<<endl;
    napln(A,N);

    /************************************************/

    cout<<("Zadejte pocet prvku mnoziny B:")<<endl;
    cin>>N1;
        if (N1<=0 || cin.fail()){
            cout<<("Nespravny vstup.")<<endl;
            return 1;
        }
    int *B=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N1); /***********/

    cout<<("Zadejte prvky mnoziny B:")<<endl;
    napln(B,N1);

    int *C=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*((N1>N)? N1:N)); /***********/

    vypis(C,porovnej(A,B,C,N,N1));

    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    return 0;
}

int napln(int *p,int n){

        int prvek,i,j;

        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>prvek; //dodelat kontrolu
            if (cin.fail()){
                cout<<("Nespravny vstup.")<<endl;
                free(p);
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                p[i]=prvek;
                for(j=0;j<i;j++){
                    if (p[i]==p[j]){
                        cout<<("Nespravny vstup.")<<endl;
                        free(p);
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is when i call napln function once (tried in separated .cpp file) it works perfectly (detecting doubled values and exit) but when i do the same for another dyn. allocated memory it won't exit and continues (message i written into console window but program flow just continues...). Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: instead of using return 1 in your main function try using exit(1). also translating the output into english would make it a little easier to follow

Comment: in C++, you may avoid to call `malloc/free`, `new[]/delete[]` is preferred. and not call memory allocator yourself is even better, so you may use `std::vector`.

Comment: Why all the C?  `int *A=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);  free(A);` looks funny.  `int *A = new int[N]; delete[] A;` is how it's done in C++, if you absolutely need dynamic storage.  Which you almost never do directly.

Comment: @cHao; I think you may want to edit that comment. It should be using `delete[] A` not `delete A`.

Comment: [OT]: your `napln` funtion return always `1`. you may use different result when error happen (and check the result) or turn into `void napln(int*, int)`.

Comment: Y it is always a mix of C/C++ , because we are learning C and C++. And to be honest i cant do the same in C and C++ even if there is cmath i am using math.h for expamle . I have to improve this significantly. Anyway thank you for comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` only ever returns from the function you're currently in.
You can use the return value of your `napln` function to decide, from outside, that the program should end, based on the return value. E.g., you could have napln return, let's say 1 on failure and 0 on success and based on the return value, you could do:

```
if(!napln(A,N))
   return 1; //return from main
```

C++ also has **exceptions** as an alternative to controlling your program flow via return values.

Alternatively, you can use the `void exit(int status)` function to exit your program, whatever your current context, though it's not a very good practice to structure your code like that.

Anyway, the code's not very well structured. For example, you should try not to repeat yourself and make the input request part of your code a function instead of copying and pasting it and changing A to B.

Comment: Hi. Problem was already solved but you are right. if(!napln(A,N))
   return 1; was solution (there was something else too but i dont get why it work one time and wont work second time... nevermind... maybe i was halucinating :) ). And about program structure you are right again, but as a newbie i prefer code...
code...
code... than code(code(code(values))) but i want to work on this :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand the identifier in your program, but maybe the problem is you free a memory twice: first is `free(p)` in function `napln`, second is `free(A)` and `free(B)` in `main`. Try not to free the pointer in function `napln`.